# compare 2 Java script objects to find differences

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have moderate knowledge on java script and I am trying to compare 2 java script objects to find the differences. Below is the code i am using in the function and not getting desired output

```
function compoare() {
  var Json1 = [
    { name: "ABC", value: "5" },
    { name: "DEF", value: "85712264" },
  ];
  var Json2 = [
    { name: "DEF", value: "85712264" },
    { name: "ABC", value: "3" },
  ];

  var obj1Keys = Object.keys(Json1);
  var obj1Values = Object.values(Json1);
  var obj2Keys = Object.keys(Json2);
  var obj2Values = Object.values(Json2);
  console.log(obj1Keys);
  console.log(obj1Values);

  for (let i = 0; i < obj1Keys.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < obj2Keys.length; j++) {
      if (obj1Keys[i] === obj2Keys[j]) {
        if (obj1Values[i] !== obj2Values[j]) {
          console.log(obj1Keys[i]);
          console.log(obj1Values[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to compare  'name' and 'value' from Json1 and check in Json2. If it found the matching 'name', then compare the 'value' for the respective 'name' . If there is a difference in  'value', then print 'name' and 'value' pair from Json1.

> Expected O/P is:  ABC, 5

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to compare the two objects attributes and values, here is a how you can achieve that, also note the [object destructor assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) I used in the first loop

```js
var Json1 = [
  { name: "ABC", value: "5" },
  { name: "DEF", value: "85712264" },
];
var Json2 = [
  { name: "DEF", value: "85712264" },
  { name: "ABC", value: "3" },
];

var obj1Keys = Object.keys(Json1);
var obj1Values = Object.values(Json1);
var obj2Keys = Object.keys(Json2);
var obj2Values = Object.values(Json2);

Json1.forEach(({name, value}) => {
   Json2.forEach((elem) => {
    if( name === elem.name && value !== elem.value) {
      console.log(name, value);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked as i expected and it allowed me to add more code with in the function. Really Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

is this work?

```js
var Json1 = [{ "name": "ABC", "value": "5" }, { "name": "DEF", "value": "85712264" }];
    var Json2 = [{ "name": "DEF", "value": "85712264" }, { "name": "ABC", "value": "3" }];

    for (let i = 0; i < Json1.length; i++) {
      const { name, value } = Json1[i];
      for (let j = 0; j < Json2.length; j++) {
        const json2 = Json2[j];
        if (name === json2.name ) {
          console.log(name, value);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation on this might be the following:

```
var Json1 = [  
{ name: "ABC", value: "5" },
  { name: "DEF", value: "85712264" },
];
var Json2 = [
  { name: "DEF", value: "85712264" },
  { name: "ABC", value: "3" },
];
var map = new Map();
Object.keys(Json1).forEach(k => map.set(Json1[k].name, Json1[k].value));
Object.keys(Json2).forEach(k => {
    if(map.has(Json2[k].name) && map.get(Json2[k].name) !== Json2[k].value)
        console.log(Json2[k].name, map.get(Json2[k].name));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function compare(){
         var Json1 = [{
            name: "ABC",
            value: "5"
        },
        {
            name: "DEF",
            value: "85712264"
        },
    ];
    var Json2 = [{
            name: "DEF",
            value: "85712264"
        },
        {
            name: "ABC",
            value: "3"
        },
];

    // since Json1 and Json2 are arrays
    // no need to use Object.keys

    Json1.forEach((current, index) => {
        // find same name item in Json2
        let json2obj = Json2.find(obj => obj.name === current.name) || {}

        // now compare value
        if (json2obj.value && current.value !== json2obj.value) {
            console.log(current.name, current.value)
        }

    })
    }

    compare()
```